# Java object oriented code to find points lying in a rectangle

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented

I created this short code as an exercise to learn and practice my OOPS. The aim is - given a string of points as `x1,y1,x2,y2...` figure out how many of them lie inside a given rectangle.

Can anyone please point out what things I can improve in this code design and best practices wise.

```java
public class Solution{

    private String points;

    public Solution(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override
    public String checkPointsInRectangle() {
        String[] numbers = points.split(", ");

        List<Point> pointList = getPointsList(numbers);

        SortedSet<Point> pointsByX =
                new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt((Point p) -> p.x)
                        .thenComparingInt((Point p) -> p.y));
        SortedSet<Point> pointsByY =
                new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt((Point p) -> p.y)
                        .thenComparingInt((Point p) -> p.x));

        pointsByX.addAll(pointList);
        pointsByY.addAll(pointList);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(-3,7,-10,10);

        Set<Point> result = getPointsInRect(rect, pointsByX, pointsByY);

        StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder();
        for(Point s : result){
            joined.append(s.x);
            joined.append(s.y);
        }
        return joined.toString();
    }

    List<Point> getPointsList(String [] points){
        List<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i< points.length-1;i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                Point point = new Point(Integer.parseInt(points[i]), Integer.parseInt(points[i + 1]));
                result.add(point);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    Set<Point> getPointsInRect(Rectangle rect, SortedSet<Point> pointsByX, SortedSet<Point> pointsByY) {
        Point minXMinY = new Point(rect.x0, rect.y0);
        Point maxXMaxY = new Point(rect.x1, rect.y1);
        Set<Point> pointsX = pointsByX.subSet(minXMinY, maxXMaxY);
        Set<Point> pointsY = pointsByY.subSet(minXMinY, maxXMaxY);
        Set<Point> rectPoints = new HashSet<>(pointsY);
        rectPoints.retainAll(pointsX);
        return rectPoints;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Point {

     final int x;       // made final so that user provided input is immutable.
     final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Added the Rectangle class as well

```java
package dummy;

public class Rectangle {

    final int x0,x1,y0,y1;

    public Rectangle(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {
        this.x0 = x0;
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y0 = y0;
        this.y1 = y1;
    }
}
```

Comment: _figure out how many of them lie inside a given rectangle_ is not true. You don't care about how many of them there are; you display all of them.

Comment: Umm... no? The getPointsInRect() function checks if points are in the given rectangle, then I add those to the rectPoints set

Comment: "How many of them" implies counting. You don't do any counting.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean _given a string of points as x1,y1,x2,y2... figure out which of them lie on the boundary of a given rectangle_ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're practicing OOP, but this doesn't make very good use of OOP patterns. `Solution` and `checkPointsInRectangle` incorrectly concern themselves with more than they should (set construction, comparison). `Solution` doesn't show an entry point and stores `points` as a member which it should not. `Point` should be responsible for its own parsing and formatting, and should be a `record` instead of a `class`. `Rectangle` should be responsible for point checking inside of its bounds.

Consider using the streaming interface, since this is really just an iterative parse, filter and format.

This:

```
for(Point s : result){
    joined.append(s.x);
    joined.append(s.y);
}
```

if intended for display purposes, wouldn't produce very useful output - there are no separators.

I'm trying to understand how your `getPointsInRect` could do what it's intended to do; I don't think it does. Set operations are not enough to calculate geometric containment unless you fill a set with every possible coordinate inside of the rect, which you don't - and even if you did, this would be pretty inefficient. Just do numeric bounds checking instead; no sets needed.

### Suggested

**Main.java**

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(-3,7, -10, 10);

        String contained = Point.parse("-11,-11,0,0,1,2")
            .filter(rect::contains)
            .map(Point::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        System.out.println(contained);
    }
}
```

**Rectangle.java**

```java
public record Rectangle(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return x0 <= p.x() && p.x() <= x1
            && y0 <= p.y() && p.y() <= y1;
    }
}
```

**Point.java**

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public record Point(int x, int y) {
    public static Stream<Point> parse(String str) {
        String[] segments = str.split(",");

        return IntStream.range(0, segments.length/2)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Point(
                Integer.parseInt(segments[2*i]),
                Integer.parseInt(segments[2*i+1])
            ));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(%d, %d)".formatted(x, y);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
(0, 0), (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thankyou ! This was really helpful, learned a lot. Specially the use of java streams